# Data accesed from redis-cli and though python are different

Tags: python-3.x, redis

I am using redis server for storing a sensor value using python script but when i am runing the code there is no error but when i am using a redis-cli for looking a data on redis server they show some value but this value is different when i am using python shell.so why this happen and what are the reason behind this.please help me

Comment: You need to provide more information. What do you mean different? How are you sure, that you make the same query in cli and in python?

Comment: when I am run this command  int(redis_db.hget(0xC1),"currVal") in python they show  output as 1 which is true as per my logic in the code. but when i am run (hget 0xC1 currVal) command in redis-cli  its show me (nil) and for initialising the server i have use this redis_db = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0, connection_pool=None)

Comment: Isn't it should be `int(redis_db.hget(0xC1,"currVal"))`? Also run `HGETALL` and see if your hash is indeed populated.